# How to annotate related object with MAX by some attribute

Tags: django, django-models, orm

```py
class Bill(models.Model):
    number = CharField(max_length=32)

class Service(models.Model):
    number = CharField(max_length=32)
    bill = ForeignKey(Bill, related_name="bill_services")
    price = IntegerField()

bills = Bill.objects.prefetch_related('bill_services').annotate(service_number_with_max_price=....)
```

Hello. How can I annotate a service **number** with max price for each Bill.
I want to use it for something like that:

```
{% for bill in bills %}
    {{ bill.service_number_with_max_price }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can annotate a [subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) to do this:

```py
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

subquery = Service.objects.filter(bill=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-price').values('number')[:1]
bills = Bill.objects.prefetch_related('bill_services').annotate(service_number_with_max_price=Subquery(subquery))
```

The subquery does the following to achieve your use case:

1. `.filter(bill=OuterRef('pk'))`: Gets `Service` objects with foreign key to outer queries current row.
2. `.order_by('-price')`: Orders the results in descending order of price.
3. `.values('number')`: Select only the `number` field.
4. `[:1]`: Limit the results to one row for the subquery.

Comment: Wow, thanks. I should read about subquery's.
Sadly, I can't order bill's cuz they should be ordered by another Service's field (another FK that I don't described) for front-end purposes.
Already solved my problem with getting service with biggest price on front-end with js.
Anyway big thanks, it really solves the problem (that I described simplified) and will be very useful to me in the future.

Comment: @Rey the ordering in the subquery is separate from any other ordering you are doing though? You can order the prefetched queryset in whatever manner you want.

Comment: @Abdul_Aziz_Barkat Oh, you are right. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the aggregate method.

```
from django.db.models import Max

query = Bill.objects.all().prefetch_related("bill_services").aggregate(max_price=Max("bill_services__price"))
```

In the template, you can access the max price of the service by

```
{% for bill in bills %}
    {{ bill.max_price }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I know about Max() =((
But I need Service number of Service with max price.
Not the max price.